# Leetcode #179 largest Number printing weird output with my c++ code (it's not about algorithm)

Tags: c++, memory, stack-overflow

So here is my code, I used recursion to compare the digits rather than the whole number

```
class comparator{
    public:
        bool operator()(int a, int b){
            return cmp(a,b);    
        }

        bool cmp(int a,int b){
            if(a == b) return true;
            std::cout << a << " " << b << '\n';
            int res = compare(a,b);
            if(res == 0 || res > 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }

        // this compares digit by digit so 9 > 30 (cause comparing 9 and 3), 4 > 20, 6 > 57 etc
        // for some cases like 3,30 where the first is the same, compare the 3 and 0, so 3 > 30

        int compare(int a,int b){
            if(a == b) return 0;

            // if both numbers are greater than 10, divide them to get to the larger digit
            if(a/10 && b/10){
                int res = compare(a/10,b/10);
                if(res == 0){
                    // if the digit before is the same then compare the current digit to see who is larger
                    int lsta = a%10, lstb = b%10;
                    return lsta-lstb;
                }

                return res;
            }

            if(a/10) {
                int res = compare(a/10,b);
                if(res == 0){
                    // similar to above but here you might have cases like 3,30 where the 3 is the same so you want to compare 3 and 0
                    int lsta = a%10, lstb = b%10;
                    return lsta-lstb;
                }
                return res;
            }

            if(b/10){
                int res = compare(a,b/10);
                if(res == 0){
                    int lsta = a%10, lstb = b%10;
                    return lsta-lstb;
                }
                return res;
            }
            return a-b;
        }
    };



    string largestNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comparator());
        string ans = "";
        for(int i : nums){
            ans += to_string(i);
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

I know the code is not exactly correct so I'm just going to go over the sequence the functions are called, when the sort function is ran, it will call the operator() function which will call the cmp function, but for the algorithm I wrote I need to know if the numbers are the same so I added another function compare which returns a int, positive for a > b, 0 for the same and negative for a < b.

I got a runtime error for the test case

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

so I added a cout under cmp which is the function that will be called right after the sort is initiated, interesting thing is I got alot of weird numbers for a and b (the parameter passed in). the output is just the first few as the whole list is very long but it's pretty much the same thing with different large number

```
117841 0
943141169 0
807416116 0
859060490 0
825308209 0
807418166 0
925906954 0
825635124 0
807417393 0
959789066 0
875574832 0
807415865 0
892483594 0
842543155 0
807418160 0
925906954 0
825766196 0
807417398 0
892483850 0
959852601 0
807416885 0
892483594 0
825570102 0
807416882 0
925906954 0
859255092 0
807416633 0
959789322 0
```

the input should be only 0 and because the numbers are printed right after it's passed in, it shouldn't have been tampered in any ways, so I'm really confused as to what happened that caused the number to be like that. I thought it could have been some memory leak in the recursion so I added a compare statement before the print statement which will return if the 2 numbers are the same(in this case since the input is all 0 it should return right away without running the recursion compare function)

Comment: The sort function requires the strict weak ordering.

Comment: `bool cmp(int a,int b){ if(a == b) return true;` -- This will not work due to not following a strict-weak-ordering.  If you had used Visual Studio, this would have instantly stopped the program with an assertion error when running against the debug runtime library.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you very much, I didn't really notice that, but why would I get weird number inputs for not using a strict weak ordering compare?

Comment: Weird numbers?  Like I said, Visual Studio would stop your program dead, and you wouldn't see any numbers.  The behavior with a bad compare function is **undefined**.